# Counting number of events underway at a timestamp

Tags: r

I have a series of timestamps marking the beginning and end of certain events.

```
library(chron)
start <- structure(c(14246.3805439815, 14246.3902662037, 14246.3909606481, 
14246.3992939815, 14246.4013773148, 14246.4034606481, 14246.4062384259, 
14246.4069328704, 14246.4069328704, 14246.4097106481, 14246.4097106481, 
14246.4104050926, 14246.4117939815, 14246.4117939815, 14246.4117939815, 
14246.4145717593, 14246.4152546296, 14246.4152662037, 14246.4152662037, 
14246.4159606481), format = structure(c("m/d/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
"times")), origin = structure(c(1, 1, 1970), .Names = c("month", 
"day", "year")), class = c("chron", "dates", "times"))

finish <- structure(c(14246.436099537, 14246.4666550926, 14246.4083217593, 
14246.4374884259, 14246.4847106481, 14246.4867939815, 14246.4305439815, 
14246.4659606481, 14246.4520717593, 14246.9097106481, 14246.4930439815, 
14246.4763773148, 14246.4326273148, 14246.4291550926, 14246.4187384259, 
14246.9145717593, 14246.4395601852, 14246.4395717593, 14246.4395717593, 
14246.4367939815), format = structure(c("m/d/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
"times")), origin = structure(c(1, 1, 1970), .Names = c("month", 
"day", "year")), class = c("chron", "dates", "times"))

events <- data.frame(start, finish)
head(event, 5)

                start              finish
1 (01/02/09 09:07:59) (01/02/09 10:27:59)
2 (01/02/09 09:21:59) (01/02/09 11:11:59)
3 (01/02/09 09:22:59) (01/02/09 09:47:59)
4 (01/02/09 09:34:59) (01/02/09 10:29:59)
5 (01/02/09 09:37:59) (01/02/09 11:37:59)
```

I now wish to count how many events are underway at specific timestamps.

```
intervals <- structure(c(14246.3958333333, 14246.40625, 14246.4166666667, 
14246.4270833333, 14246.4375), format = structure(c("m/d/y", 
"h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", "times")), origin = structure(c(1, 
1, 1970), .Names = c("month", "day", "year")), class = c("chron", 
"dates", "times"))

intervals

[1] (01/02/09 09:30:00) (01/02/09 09:45:00) (01/02/09 10:00:00) (01/02/09 10:15:00) (01/02/09 10:30:00)
```

So the output I desire is as follows:

```
            intervals count
1 (01/01/09 09:30:00)     3
2 (01/01/09 09:45:00)     7
3 (01/01/09 10:00:00)    19
4 (01/01/09 10:15:00)    18
5 (01/01/09 10:30:00)    12
```

While the problem is trivial to solve programatically, I wish to accomplish this for 210,000 intervals and over 1.2 million events. My current approach involves leveraging the `data.table` package and the `&` operator to check whether an interval lies between the start and end time of each event.

```
library(data.table)
events <- data.table(events)
data.frame(intervals, count = sapply(1:5, function(i) sum(events[, start <= intervals[i] & intervals[i] <= finish])))
```

But considering the size of my data, this approach takes a very long time to run. Any advice on better alternatives to accomplish this in R?

Cheers.

Comment: You say you are using the `data.table` package.  Care to show us the code you use?  Your last line of code doesn't use `data.table` at all.  You are simply using base R on a `data.frame`.

Comment: The data.table package allows you to '&' as an column index. The following throws an error:


`events <- data.frame(events)

data.frame(int, count = sapply(1:5, function(i) sum(events[, start <= int[i] & int[i] <= finish])))`

Comment: Subtle...  Get it now.  D'oh.

Answer (score 3):

The secret of fast performing code in R is to keep everything in vector, or arrays, which are really just arrays in disguise.

Here is a solution that makes use exclusively of base R arrays.  Your sample of data is tiny so I use `replicate` and  `system.time` combined to measure performance.

My solution is roughly 6 times faster than your solution with `sapply` and `data.table`.  (My solution takes 0.6 seconds to solve your small sample data set 1,000 times.)

Timing your solution

```
system.time(replicate(1000, 
    XX <- data.frame(
      intervals, 
      count = sapply(1:5, function(i) sum(events[, start <= intervals[i] & intervals[i] <= finish])))
))

   user  system elapsed 
   4.04    0.05    4.11
```

My solution.  First create two helper functions to create equal sized arrays with events running down the columns and intervals running across the rows.  Then do a simple vector comparison followed by `colSums`:

```
event.array <- function(x, interval){
  len <- length(interval)
  matrix(rep(unclass(x), len), ncol=len)
}

intervals.array <- function(x, intervals){
  len <- length(x)
  matrix(rep(unclass(intervals), len), nrow=len, byrow=TRUE)
} 


a.start <- event.array(start, intervals)
a.finish <- event.array(finish, intervals)
a.intervals <- intervals.array(start, intervals)

data.frame(intervals, 
           count=colSums(a.start <= a.intervals & a.finish >= a.intervals))

            intervals count
1 (01/02/09 09:30:00)     3
2 (01/02/09 09:45:00)     7
3 (01/02/09 10:00:00)    19
4 (01/02/09 10:15:00)    18
5 (01/02/09 10:30:00)    12
```

Timing my solution

```
system.time(replicate(1000, 
  YY <- data.frame(
          intervals, 
          count=colSums(a.start <= a.intervals & a.finish >= a.intervals))
))

   user  system elapsed 
   0.67    0.02    0.69 

all.equal(XX, YY)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Andrie! Your solution indeed seems like a good alternative to mine. There is one glitch though: a.intervals <- intervals.array(start, intervals) seems to make R stop responding when start has length over approx. 16,000 and intervals has length of approx. 50,000 (which is 1/4 of my real interval data). Any ideas on how to overcome this apart from using smaller chuncks of intervals and combing the data at the end?

Comment: I'm not a big data expert, so can only offer two options.  1) Cut it into chunk, as you suggest (which may or may not be time efficient in the end). 2) Use a bigger machine - have you considered Amazon EC2 or Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `dim()` instead of `sum()` and `ldply()` instead of `sapply()` might be faster?

```
b<-function(i,df){ data.frame(i, count=dim(df[with(df, start<i & finish> i),])[1])};
ldply(intervals, b, events);

         i count
1 14246.40     3
2 14246.41     7
3 14246.42    19
4 14246.43    18
5 14246.44    12
```

I'm not familiar with the chron library so I did't make `i` come out as a timestamp. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your solution takes twice as long to run than what I currently have.

`system.time(ldply(intervals, b, events))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.005 

system.time(data.frame(intervals, count = sapply(1:5, function(i) sum(events[, start <= intervals[i] & intervals[i] <= finish]))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002`

But this may not hold if I run it over my entire data set.

Comment: `ldply` ultimately wraps around `split` and `lapply` and will in most cases be quite a bit slower than other alternatives.  I am a huge fan of `plyr` but if performance is an issue then avoid `plyr`.